# windows azure not available in my country

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

I would like to explore the azure platform and create applications which make use of azure. So i searched for a tutorial which told me to first create an account, yet my country is NOT AVAILABLE so I cannot create an account! Is there any way in which I can still develop applications using azure platform? Is it true there's some form of emulator?

Can anyone be kind enough to give me a few starting links because I have no fundamental skills in this area?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It might be helpful if you indicate which country you are in.

Comment: I also have the same problem, I am from Suriname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install the tools + SDK, you'll get a local runtime that emulates compute and storage (storage is actually *stored* in a local SQL instance, defaulting to SQL Express). You can use SQL Server or SQL Azure for local database simulation. The things you don't get are ACS, Service Bus, and Cache (and maybe something else I'm missing :) ). Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433135.aspx) for differences between real storage and simulated storage, and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432960.aspx) for Compute differences.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So if I am understanding you correctly, I will not be having an online database? Can you please tell me how I can use SQL Azure for local database simulation? At the moment all I have is a COMPUTE and STORAGE emulator. I am also planning to connect to mobile phones and I am afraid that a simulation will not be able to cater my needs!

Comment: You're correct, unless you are able to setup an account there are no legitimate ways to make use of Azure in the cloud.  The FAQ lists the countries that Azure is currently available in: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/faq/  I'd contact MS in your country to see if/when Azure will be available in your country.

Answer (score 2):

The emulator is part of the Azure SDK.